# Como criar uma Jar e exportar do CVS?

Tags: java

Preciso transformar um projeto em Jar no CVS mas não estou conseguindo, alguém sabe como fazer o passo a passo?

Comment: Daniel, você poderia dar mais detalhes? O que você já tentou, qual erro está dando? quais ferramentas está usando?

Comment: CVS é um controle de versão. Você consegue baixar este projeto em algum IDE?